# Countably closed posets don't add a new uncountable W-free set. (Or $\kappa$-Aronszajn trees remain $\kappa$-Aronszajn.)

Tags: logic, set-theory, forcing

This is a follow up to [$PFA \implies SOCA$. (Or using forcing to prove theorems unrelated to consistency.)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1991107/pfa-implies-soca-or-using-forcing-to-prove-theorems-unrelated-to-consistenc).
Pertinent definitions can be found there.

(**Actually, if you prefer, you can skip all the details on PFA and SOCA and just explain to me how to get the $x_\xi$ from the exercise and hint below and how to get the set $\{x_\xi:\xi<\kappa\}$ to be an element of $M$ and it will probably be very useful to me anyway.**)

In the second paragraph to that proof, Kunen says that as $\mathbb{P}$ is countable closed, it preserves the fact that no uncountable subset of $E$ is $W$-free. It says it can be argued in the same way as this exercise:

[image]

I have an argument but I doubt its validity a bit (Primarily because I'm unsure if I'm "working in $M$"):

Suppose $p$ forces that $\mathring{C}$ is an uncountable $W$-free subset of $E$. We find a sequence $p\geq p_0\geq...p_\xi\geq...$ for $\xi<\omega_1$, along with elements $x_\xi\in E$ such that $p_\xi\Vdash x_\xi\in \mathring{C}$ and the $x_\xi$ are all different. To do this fix a generic $G$ with $p\in G$. As $M[G]\models |C|=\aleph_1$ there must be some $x_0\in C$ so get $p_0\leq p$ such that $p\Vdash x_0\in C$. Suppose $\xi<\omega_1$ and that we've defined $p_\alpha$ and $x_\alpha$ for $\alpha<\xi$. As this recursion is taking place in $M$, the set $\{x_\alpha:\alpha<\xi\}$ is in $M$ and $M[G]\models C\setminus \{x_\alpha:\alpha<\xi\}\neq \emptyset$ so get a $x_\xi\in C\setminus \{x_\alpha:\alpha<\xi\}$ and a $p_\xi$ that forces $x_\xi\in \mathring{C}$. We can assume this $p_\xi$ is below all the previously defined $p_\alpha$ as the poset is countably closed. This way $\{x_\xi:\xi<\omega_1\}$ is in $M$ (as it was defined by recursion in $M$) and given $x_\alpha$ and $x_\beta$ WLOG assume $\alpha<\beta$, so $p_\beta$ forces that they're both in $C$ and then $(x_\alpha,x_\beta)\notin W$. Which implies $\{x_\xi:\xi<\omega_1\}\in M$ is $W$-free.

Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you write "fix a generic $G$," and then never use it; this is an indication that you are in fact reasoning inside $M$! Specifically, do away with the generic and just focus on the (definable!) forcing relation itself. *Everything I write below takes place inside $M$*:

Suppose $\mathbb{P}$ is countably closed, but *could* add an uncountable $W$-free subset of $E$. Let $\nu$ be a name, and $p$ a condition that forces "$\nu$ is an uncountable $W$-free subset of $E$". Let $\lhd$ be some well-ordering of $\mathbb{P}$, and $\prec$ some well-ordering of $E$ (these exists since $M\models AC$ - for any set in $M$, there's a well-ordering of that set also in $M$). Then we define an $\omega_1$-sequence of conditions and reals as follows:

> $p_\alpha$ is the $\lhd$-least condition stronger than $p$ and every $p_\beta$ for $\beta<\alpha$ such that for some $e\in E$, we have $p_\alpha\Vdash e\in \nu$ but $p_\beta\not\Vdash e\in\nu$ for any $\beta<\alpha$; and we let $e_\alpha$ be the $\prec$-least such $e$.

It's a good exercise to show that $p_\alpha$ and $e_\alpha$ are in fact defined for every $\alpha<\omega_1$. You'll use the countable closure of $\mathbb{P}$, together with the fact that each individual condition can only force countably many things into $\nu$ (since otherwise we'd get an uncountable $W$-free set right there).

Then $\{e_\alpha: \alpha<\omega_1\}$ is an uncountable $W$-free subset of $E$, *in the ground model* (since the above definition by transfinite recursion took place entirely in the ground model).

---

Note that I used that $M$ satisfies AC, above. What if $M$ *doesn't* satisfy AC - if I force over a model in which choice fails, do things still work out nicely?

The answer, sadly (or excitingly!), is *no*. Indeed, we can even have forcings that are countably closed but add reals! For a very silly example of this, let $M$ be a model of ZF which contains an *infinite, Dedekind-finite set* $D$ (that is, an infinite set into which $\omega$ does not embed) and let $\mathbb{P}_{stupid}$ be the partial order consisting of *pairs* $p=(\sigma, \tau)$, where $\sigma$ is a finite string of natural numbers, $\tau$ is a finite string of **distinct** elements of $D$, and $\vert\sigma\vert=\vert\tau\vert$ (order $\mathbb{P}_{stupid}$ in the obvious way).

Then clearly forcing with $\mathbb{P}_{stupid}$ adds a real - forget the $D$ nonsense, the left coordinates are Cohen forcing! But because of the $D$ nonsense, $M$ thinks that *every sequence $p_0\ge p_1\ge p_2\ge . . .$ is eventually constant*, and hence that $\mathbb{P}_{stupid}$ is countably closed! (See also [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/139277/how-to-make-countably-closed-forcing-nice-without-choice).)

Comment: '[..], sadly (or excitingly!), [..]' It's definitely the latter - nice answer!

Comment: @NoahScweber Thank you, this is just the answer I needed, the well orders seem to be a great solution. But this is still confusing to me: When defining the $\omega_1$ sequence, I'm having trouble getting $p_\alpha$ to force $e\in\nu$ for some $e\in E$. I know it forces $\pi\in\nu$ for some name $\pi$. But I can't say this name is a canonical name for some $e\in E$, which is what I want. (This is the problem that I attempted to fix by fixing a generic $G$ and then grabbing some $e\in E\cap\nu$ in the extension and then a condition that forced it there, but this might not be "working in $M$".)

Comment: @Mingus That's a reasonable worry - countable closure to the rescue! Remember that since $\mathbb{P}$ is countably closed, it adds no new reals! So given a condition $q$ and a name $\pi$ such that $q\Vdash\pi\in E$, we can find a *canonical* name for a real, $\dot{r}$, and a condition $q'\le q$ such that $q'\Vdash \pi=\dot{r}$. This is a trick specific to countably closed forcings (or more generally, forcings not adding any reals - note that such forcings which are non-countably-closed exist, witness Namba or Prikry).

Comment: @Mingus Note that in the previous section, I conflated elements of $E$ with reals. This might seem suspicious, but it's fine - remember that $E$ is a subset of a separable metric space, and every such injects into $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$.